# Problem with Python modules

Tags: python, django, dreamhost

I'm uploading my first Django app to my Dreamhost server. My app uses [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) package and since I can't install it in the default location ( /usr/lib/python2.3/site-packages/xlwt ), I installed it on another location by:

```
python setup.py install --home=$HOME
```

Then xlwt is installed here:

```
/home/myuser/lib/python/xlwt/
```

After that, I add this folder to de env var PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/myuser/lib/python
```

... And in a python promt I can do this (without problems)

```
import xlwt
```

... But if I do the same thing in my app code, I have the follow error:

```
Could not import ISI.restaurante.views. Error was: No module named xlwt
```

[where ISI.restaurante.views is my code where I do the import]

Could u help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PYTHONPATH may only be set when you run from the shell, you can set path programatically from python using

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/myuser/lib/python')
```

Comment: omg, noob error!

A lot of THAAAAAANKS! :D

Now, it's working!